# Machine Generation of Art Patterns in Vector Fields

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, machine-learning, massive

I am trying to rewrite this article:[We draw, programming. Machine-generated generation of artistic patterns in vector fields](https://proglib.io/p/risuem-programmiruya-mashinnaya-generaciya-hudozhestvennyh-uzorov-v-vektornyh-polyah-2020-02-06) (Russian language) from pseudo-code in Python. I am new to ML, hence the following question arises: How to build a grid of angles and output it through PyCharm? I am at this stage:

```
import numpy as np
import math
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

width = 100
height = 100

left_x = int(width * -0.5)
right_x = int(width * 1.5)
top_y = int(height * -0.5)
bottom_y = int(height * 1.5)

resolution = int(width * 0.01)

num_columns = int((right_x - left_x) / resolution)
num_rows = int((bottom_y - top_y) / resolution)

grid=np.ndarray((num_columns, num_rows))
grid[:,:]=math.pi * 0.25
```

In this code, I create a grid array in which 200 rows and 200 columns, into which the angle 'default_angle' is inserted. Please tell me whether I’m moving in the right direction and how to "draw" a grid, as in an attached link. So far I think I need to use matplotlib.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make several steps to recreate this:

1. create vector field based on some function or equation
2. normalize arrows for proper display
3. draw line
   3.1. set starting parameters
   3.2. set `while` out condition
   3.3. calculate new position based on angle from starting point
   3.4. get new position index --> net new angle
   3.5. update starting positions
4. draw vector field and line

import numpy as np
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

```
size = 50
X = np.arange(1, size, 1)
Y = np.arange(1, size, 1)
U, V = np.meshgrid(X, Y)

# Normalize the arrows:
U = U / np.sqrt(U**2 + V**2)
V = V / np.sqrt(U**2 + V**2)

# create angles field
data = []
for i in np.linspace(0, 180, Y.shape[0]):
    data.append([i]*X.shape[0])

angle = np.array(data)

# set starting parameters
x_start_position = 2
y_start_position = 2
step_length = 1.0
point_angle = angle[x_start_position, y_start_position]
line_coordinates = [[x_start_position, y_start_position]]

# collect line points for each step
while x_start_position >= 2:

    # calculate tep based on angle
    x_step = step_length * np.cos(point_angle*np.pi/180)
    y_step = step_length * np.sin(point_angle*np.pi/180)

    # calculate new position
    x_new_position = x_start_position + x_step
    y_new_position = y_start_position + y_step

    # get array index of new position
    x_new_index = int(x_new_position)
    y_new_index = int(y_new_position)

    # get new angle
    point_angle = angle[y_new_index, x_new_index]

    # update start position
    x_start_position = x_new_position
    y_start_position = y_new_position

    # collect results
    line_coordinates.append([x_new_position, y_new_position])

# set line coordinates
line_data = np.array(line_coordinates)
x_line = line_data[:,0]
y_line = line_data[:,1]

# plot field
plt.quiver(X, Y, U, V, color='black', angles=angle, width=0.005)
# plot line
plt.plot(x_line, y_line, '-', color='red')
plt.show()
```

**Output:**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I believe you need to take a look at meshgrid from numpy

from the meshgrid documentation examples:

```
x = np.arange(-5, 5, 0.1)
y = np.arange(-5, 5, 0.1)
xx, yy = np.meshgrid(x, y, sparse=True)
z = np.sin(xx**2 + yy**2) / (xx**2 + yy**2)
h = plt.contourf(x,y,z)
```

Edit. After seeing you r link a better resource is the [matplotlib quiver demo](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/gallery/images_contours_and_fields/quiver_simple_demo.html#sphx-glr-gallery-images-contours-and-fields-quiver-simple-demo-py)

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

X = np.arange(-10, 10, 1)
Y = np.arange(-10, 10, 1)
U, V = np.meshgrid(X, Y)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
q = ax.quiver(X, Y, U, V)
ax.quiverkey(q, X=0.3, Y=1.1, U=10,
             label='Quiver key, length = 10', labelpos='E')

plt.show()
```